got wrong when implementing FromData trait for an enum in rocket
I want to implement an interface for registering, which has two different ways. So I wrote two different types
#[derive(Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Clone,Eq, PartialEq,FromForm)]
pub struct AddUser{ //直接添加成员
    #[field(name="name")]
    name : String,
    #[field(name="pwd")]
    pwd: String,
    #[field(name="organization")]
    organization:String, // 组织的uuid
    #[field(name="phone")]
    phone:Option<String>,
    #[field(name="email")]
    email:Option<String>,
    #[field(name="workId")]
    work_id:Option<String>,
    #[field(name="gender")]
    gender:Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Clone,Eq, PartialEq,FromForm)]
pub struct RegisterUser{ 
    #[field(name="phone")]
    phone:String,
    #[field(name="name")]
    name:String,
    #[field(name="pwd")]
    pwd:String,
    #[field(name="organization")]
    organization:String 
}

then I want to reuse one interface so I put them into an enum
#[derive(Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Clone,Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum MoreUser{
    Add(AddUser),
    Create(RegisterUser)
}

then I impl FromData trait for enum MoreUser like this
impl<'r> FromData<'r> for MoreUser{
    type Error = ();

    async fn from_data(_req: &'r Request<'_>, data: Data<'r>) -> Outcome<'r,Self,Self::Error> {
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        if let Err(_) = data.open(Default::default()).take(1024).read_to_string(&mut buffer){
            return Outcome::Failure((Status::InternalServerError,()));
        }
        if let Ok(add_user) = serde_urlencoded::from_str::<AddUser>(&buffer) {
            return Outcome::Success(MoreUser::Add(add_user));
        } else if let Ok(register_user) = serde_urlencoded::from_str::<RegisterUser>(&buffer){
            return Outcome::Success(MoreUser::Create(register_user));
        }
        Outcome::Failure((Status::UnprocessableEntity,()))
    }
}

the interface as follow
#[post("/register",data="<register_data>")]
pub async fn register(
    db:GdData,
    validator:&State<ValidateData>,
    register_data: MoreUser
) -> Result<RtData<RegisterResult>,Status> {

After all the compilor told me
async fn from_data(req: &'r Request<'>, data: Data<'r>) -> Outcome<'r,Self,Self::Error> {
|                       ^ lifetimes do not match method in trait
Environment: Win10
I'm new in rust, facing the lifetime problem makes me don't know how to do. I do did some search  but nothing helpful, I also asked the chatgpt, and it doesn't work..

Your signature has to match exactly the one from the trait: fn from_data<'life0, 'async_trait>( req: &'r Request<'life0>, data: Data<'r>) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Outcome<'r, Self>> + Send + 'async_trait>> where Self: 'async_trait, 'r: 'async_trait, 'life0: 'async_trait including generic lifetime parameters and bounds.
